# Import packages for dash sub-app already existing

Tags: python, python-import, plotly-dash

I created a `Dash` application which is running fine on it's own (with no import issues). Other users also created application that we now want to merge into a single application with a general index linking every application. I can't find a solution to load a package I created. I want to run the application on it's own (debugging purpose) and via the general index (production purpose).

Here is the structure for my app (similar to what is detailed [here on the Dash documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/urls)):

```
+ app.py --> creates the dash server
+ layout.py --> Defines my page layout
+ callbacks.py --> I imported packages here (import package as pk) that will fail when run via the general index
+ package --> the packages I created
```

After I merged the project, my structure looks like that (via a `git submodule add`):

```
+ app.py
+ index.py --> will call the layouts
+ initial app folder (git submodule from structure above)
  + __init__.py
  + the files above
```

When I start the server, I get the error message `pk.something error, pk is not defined`. I can't find a solution to have the application run standalone and within the general index. I tried to move the import (in `app.py` or in the new `__init__.py`) but nothing works.
My next attempt will be to move the package in a new subfolder. Does anyone know if that will work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work via the `app.py` file. I don't know if it's a proper solution and I feel I can scale my application in a decent manner. I moved my scripts into folders with a `__init__.py`

in `app.py`, I added:

```
from package import my_package
```

in `callbacks.py`, I changed the import;

```
from app import my_package as pk
```

Comments are welcome for improvements. I would like to know how far I am from the best solution.